# Insert data from arraylist to tables

Tags: java, sql, json, postgresql, jdbc

ok, I am a newbie. I have two ArrayList and I want to insert data from the arralylist to table. one arraylist is for the table parameters to insert and other arraylist for inserting the values of the table.

I have tried searching if there was a dynamic way to insert but could not find any.

```
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> values= new ArrayList<>();
list.add("userid");
list.add("name");
list.add("email");

values.add(userID);
values.add(name);
values.add(email);

String sql = "insert into users (" + list + ") values( " + values + ")";

stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

I want to insert the data into the table. but parameters like userid should be in ''(quotes) and name should be in ''(quotes). but they are not converted automatically. is there any other way to do the same task?
IS there any way to get the data from JSON and insert into tables locally?

Answer (score 2):

You should **not** not concatenate values like that into a SQL String. Use a `PreparedStatement` instead:

```
String sql = "insert into users (userid, name, email) values (?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt  = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
```

The preferred way to insert multiple rows, is to use batching

```
for (int i=0; i < values.size(); i++) {
   pstmt.setString(i+1, values.get(i);
}
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

---

Passing a value for a column name `userid` as a String seems to be wrong to begin with. Usually those are stored as integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.join` method to compose the query:

```
String sql = "insert into users (" + String.join(", ", list) + ") values( '" + String.join("', '", values) + "')";
```

But such by-hand sql composing from raw `String`s is dangerous and can be vulnerable to injection attacks. I suggest using other solutions like orm.

Comment: what about integers? integers wont work there? how to handle integer data?

Comment: I thoulght all of them were `String`s. No, for `Integer`s it won't work. As said, that's not the way to do this.